# Getting unshifted key

Tags: javascript, keyboard, cross-browser

Is there a way to get the "unshifted" value of a key with KeyboardEvent.key after keydown?

So far I've been using String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase(), but that only works with some keys. The alternative would be using KeyboardEvent.keyCode/which, but that has it's own shortcomings (being unable to anticipate the value of the key with different keyboard layouts). Besides, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) lists both .keyCode and .which as deprecated in favor of .key.